# Name for Earth?

Tags: soft-question, astrophysics, terminology, earth

What is the proper word for 'Earth', as in 'Solar' and 'Lunar'? I cannot find this anywhere; I am guessing there is a word that starts with *geo*?

Comment: well instead of the greek root it is using the latin one as you can see in the answer, consistent with the latin roots of the others

Comment: Terrestrial is the scientific usage regarding the terrain of any planet. There is no (official) special name for, say, the *Earth's radius* or *Earth's gravity* and even if there are, they aren't popular. I think English.SE will be able to help you find the best word which fits this intention. Different religions and cultures have different names for the earth, like Gaya (Greek), Nandini (Indian), Midgard (Norse) etc. but greek and latin derivatives are used in literature if used at all. Rule of thumb: Name of Earth is "Earth". Nobody cares even if you call it the "3rd Rock from the Sun".

Comment: Terra (Latin for earth, unfortunately originally more in the sense of dirt underneath you). It is very unfortunate that few ancient civilizations incorporated knowledge of the ball-shape of earth into their languages. If world is good enough, "mundus" would be your Latin word. But world to the ancient Romans meant the larger surroundings of the Mediterranean, nothing truly ocean-spanning.

Comment: To go to nouns: Terra, Luna, Sol. The terms you gave are the English versions of the associated adjectives.

Comment: @pyramids: I think as landlubbers, a term like, say, TerraOceana (actually used for seabed) wouldn't be appropriate for us to describe a planet. I often associate Gaya/Gaia to be colorful green, brown and blue because of various depictions of the deity as a walking rainforest. So, if need be, I propose something like "Gaiec" to be used synonymous to "Terra"

Answer (score 3):

Technically this question is off topic and would belong in an astronomy SE, but the answers you probably are seeking are terrestrial or terran depending on whether it is a person or an object. Terran has been sorta scooped up by the Starcraft community though so terrestrial is used in almost all cases to my knowledge.

Comment: Note that Astronomy & Astrophysics questions *are* on topic here.

Comment: Generally those questions are quite different from this type of question, but I don't really mind either way as long as the question is answered.

Comment: They tried to have an astronomy.se but it did not take, so it was absorbed here

Comment: @annav And it's been launched out of Area51 again and is [currently in beta status](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Tellus, Telluric are used too.

Answer (score 1):

I think Terran is as good a word as any, as is Geo.   Thinking of terms where Solar or Lunar are used.

Solar Gravity, 
Lunar Gravity, 
Terran Gravity, or Earth's Gravity.

Solar Magnetic Field, 
Lunar Magnetic Field (which, I'm not sure there is one),
Earth's Magnetic Field or Geo-Magnetic Field is also used.

Earth's, Geo or Terran are the best 3 options I can think of.    Non-Anthropomorphic is sometimes used to describe natural events on earth, but technically Non-Anthropomorphic doesn't mean earth it simply means not by human means.